# .eep file generation in MPLAB X

Tags: avr-gcc, mplab, eeprom

I use MPLAB X. I want enable .eep file generating. How I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable .eep file generation [look at](https://github.com/AndreiCherniaev/Const_EEPROM_Atmega_test) [image]